# Powershell : Comparing all elements of an array to see if they are all the same

Tags: string, powershell, compare

Is there a simple way to compare all elements in an array in order to return if they are are all identicals strings ? other than by a loop ???

Example :

```
$array = @('123', '123', '123', '123')
#do something that returns TRUE

$array = @('2553', '123', '123', '123')
#do something that returns FALSE
```

thanks

Answer (score 2):

Use [`Group-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/group-object?view=powershell-7.4) and check if the group of objects are equal to `1`:

```bash
$array = @('123', '123', '123', '123')
@($array | Group-Object -NoElement).Count -eq 1 # True
$array = @('2553', '123', '123', '123')
@($array | Group-Object -NoElement).Count -eq 1 # False
```

Another simple way is casting [`HashSet<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.hashset-1?view=net-8.0) to the collection:

```bash
$array = @('123', '123', '123', '123')
([System.Collections.Generic.HashSet[string]] $array).Count -eq 1 # True
$array = @('2553', '123', '123', '123')
([System.Collections.Generic.HashSet[string]] $array).Count -eq 1 # False
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's two more options for you:

**use a HashSet**

```
$array = '123', '123', '123', '123'
[System.Collections.Generic.HashSet[string]]::new([string[]]$array).Count -eq 1 # True

$array = '2553', '123', '123', '123'
[System.Collections.Generic.HashSet[string]]::new([string[]]$array).Count -eq 1 # False
```

**use Linq**

```
$array = '123', '123', '123', '123'
@([System.Linq.Enumerable]::Distinct([string[]] $array)).Count -eq 1 # True

$array = '2553', '123', '123', '123'
@([System.Linq.Enumerable]::Distinct([string[]] $array)).Count -eq 1 # False
```